# How to paste a 2D array (with headers) into another sheet with column headers randomly set using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The data:

```
[
 ["ID","Variação","Nome Site","Obs"],//Headers
 [11602,185,"Camisa Teste","Teste da Observação"] //To be pasted
]
```

This is how the destination is:

| Obs | Nome Site | Variação | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I understand I could take the approach below, but considering that the dataset has more then 40 columns, this is not that feasible:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,2,4).getValues();
var obs = data.map(function(e){return e[0];});
var NomeSite = data.map(function(e){return e[1];});
...
```

How would I go about finding the header and "pasting" the data in that case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to rearrange the values by your expected header.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var expectedHeader = ["Obs", "Nome Site", "Variação", "ID"]; // Please set your expected header.

// This sample value is from your question.
var data = [
  ["ID", "Variação", "Nome Site", "Obs"],
  [11602, 185, "Camisa Teste", "Teste da Observação"]
];

var [headers, ...rows] = data;
const obj = rows.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => (o[h] = r[j], o), {}));
var res = obj.map(o => expectedHeader.map(h => o[h] || ""));
console.log(res) // [["Teste da Observação","Camisa Teste",185,11602]]
```

- When this script is used, `[11602, 185, "Camisa Teste", "Teste da Observação"]` is rearranged to `["Teste da Observação","Camisa Teste",185,11602]`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

I like Tanaike, but I'm a little scared of `reduce()` function. So here is my variant without `reduce()`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var header = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0];

  var data = [
    ["ID","Variação","Nome Site","Obs"],
    [11602,185,"Camisa Teste","Teste da Observação"]
  ]

  var indexes = header.map(x => data[0].indexOf(x));
  data = data.map(x => indexes.map(i => x.slice()[0] = x[i]));

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi! What would be the tweak to make it return only the array elements that are not null. Should I post a specific question? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Not sure if I understand the problem. What the elements? Rows of the table? Cells of the row? Probably it makes sense to ask a new question and provide an example of the data with these null elements. The question doesn't look to difficult. I think you will get the answer quickly.

Comment: Got that figured out. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Yuri! Can this be used with an object as the ```data```, or this deserves a specific question?

Comment: This particular snippet iterates over the data array with `map()` method. Object has no method `map()` so you can't use this code. Probably it will be enough just to replace `data.map(e => e...)` with a classic loop `for (i in data) { data[i] = ... }`. It depends on how your object looks like.