# How can I exclude null elements from data array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using Yuri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71381375/11832197) to a question, but found myself in a new situation and I haven't quite understood each step of this method here:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var header = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0];

  var data = [
    ["ID","Variação","Nome Site","Obs"],
    [11602,185,"Camisa Teste","Teste da Observação"]
  ]

  var indexes = header.map(x => data[0].indexOf(x));
  data = data.map(x => indexes.map(i => x.slice()[0] = x[i]));

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Here's what the result looks like:

```
let result = [
           ["ID","Variação","Nome Site","Obs", "", ""],
           [11602,185,"Camisa Teste","Teste da Observação", "", ""]
         ]
```

Now, this is returning `data` with nulls. How can I make it return only mapped array elements?
So, instead of heaving an array length of 6, that'd be only 4.
Expected Result:

```
let expectedResult = [
           ["ID","Variação","Nome Site","Obs"],
           [11602,185,"Camisa Teste","Teste da Observação"]
         ]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to filter the inner values:

```js
let result = [
  ["ID", "Variação", "Nome Site", "Obs", "", ""],
  [11602, 185, "Camisa Teste", "Teste da Observação", "", ""]
]
result = result.map(x => x.filter(y => y))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove nulls

```
function test() {
Logger.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,null,4,null,5,''].filter(e => e)))
}

Execution log
7:48:37 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:48:37 PM  Info    [1,2,3,4,5]
7:48:38 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Empty strings are another way of creating nulls

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason why you are having null elements in your array is that the cells next to your header have `" "` or space character in it. Since you are using `getDataRange()` it will also include those " " characters in your array.

**Example:**

Here, I added space character to cells **E1** and **F1**:

[image]

Here are the values of `data` after using map function:

[image]

If I remove the values of cells **E1** and **F1** the output of data is:

[image]

Null values can also occur if the values below the header overlap the number of columns in your header.

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Solution:**

Instead of using `getDataRange()`, explicitly define the range you are using for the header. You can use either `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` or `getRange(a1Notation)`.

### Reference:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)