# How to map object values according to the column headers on a Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using Yuri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71381375/11832197) when I have 2 multidimensional arrays to map one's values according to the other and `setValues()` correctly - column index wise.

Now, I have an `Object` like the one below, but I couldn't manage to convert the solution linked above to serve the same purpose and I'd appreciate a little help.

```
const e = {
  "authMode": "FULL", "namedValues": {
    "Timestamp": ["8/24/2022 14:13:53"],
    "Name:": ["Test Name"],
    "Primary contact's name:": ["John Doe"],
    "Primary contact's email:": ["john@email.com"]
  },
  "range": {
    "columnEnd": 26, "columnStart": 1, "rowEnd": 5, "rowStart": 5
  },
  "source": {},
  "triggerUid": "678678678",
  "values": ["8/24/2022 14:13:53", "Test Name", "John Doe", "john@email.com"]
}
```

This is my unsuccessful shot at it:

```
function saveResponse() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dbSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DB');
  const dbHeaders = dbSheet.getRange("A1:1").getValues()[0];

  let indexes = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < dbHeaders.length; r++) {
    for (let a = 0; a < Object.keys(e.namedValues).length; a++) {
      if (dbHeaders[r].indexOf(Object.keys(e.namedValues)[a]) > -1) {
        indexes.push(r);
      }
    }
  }
 //The second part is completely blank (or dark) to me
}
```

Now, organizing the object's values so that they can be placed into the spreadsheet according to the indexes found is where I can't get to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function saveResponse(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('DB');
  const hs = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let r = [];
  hs.forEach(h => r.push(e.namedValues[h][0]));
  sh.appendRow(r);
}
```

Comment: I guess that in the future if they shift the questions, the order may change. So there would have to be a dynamic column mapping, wouldn't it? Thank you

Comment: As long as the header matches the e.namedValues keys you are okay.  If they don't match then neither way works.

Comment: As per your approach, I guess that is would be okay to push keys and values into arrays, concatenate them and dynamically map the resulting one according to linked answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  If the headers are not equal to the e.nameValues keys then neither system works.  The header array give you the order of the colums and the named values tells you what the answers are.  It doesn't need to be more complicated than that.